# Replacing word in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to replace two words with one in a file.

`sed 's/will not/ain't/g' codes_word`

The above doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

replace `'` with `"`

output

```
shEll$ echo "Hello World!" | sed "s/World/ain't/g"                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Hello ain't!
```

Comment: OP - ClaudioM quickly recognized that `ain't` has an single quote. So, sed feels that single quote ends after `ain` like this: `sed 's/will not/ain'`. That's not what you'd expect. So, change `'` with `"` so that sed knows everything between `"` is to be treated for find/replace.

Comment: Ok so I have: sed "s/will not/ain't/g" ... When I put the file name at the end, nothing comes out.

Comment: @zedfoxus, thanks for clarifications ;)

Comment: @user5442073 could you please show the content of your file? try to replace ain't with ain\'t I mean: sed "s/World/ain\'t/g"

Comment: I've done this: echo "Hello World" >myFile, execute sed "s/World/ain\'t/g" myFile and it works

Comment: Code:
There is no emotion, there is peace. 
There is no ignorance, there is knowledge. 
There is no passion, there is serenity. 
There is no chaos, there is harmony.
There is no death, there is the Force. 

 So wait, I'm relacing is no with aint.

That's the word code file.

Comment: I've made a test with the content posted.. I've put "word to change" in the code, executed this: sed "s/word to change/ain't/g" myTemp and it works: "... I'm relacing is no with ain't."